# All the IMAP folders of multiple accounts in wanderlust

Tags: imap, wanderlust

I have two IMAP accounts, I'd like to see all my IMAP folders for both.

With only one account I use "%/" in my .folders file and it works well (but I have the `(setq elmo-imap4-default-server ...` & co. in my .emacs).

With two accounts I cannot make it work. 
I think the problem is that I'm not able to specify credentials for the two "%/".
Is there a solution?

Example ~/.folders:

```
AccountA {
    %INBOX:username/clear@imap.serverA.com:993!        "Inbox"
    %/
}
AccountB {
    %INBOX:username/clear@imap.serverB.com:993!        "Inbox"
    %/
}
```

Comment: Have you already carefully gone through the Emacs wiki Wanderlust examples and tried them out?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WlMultipleAccounts

Comment: @lawlist yes, I have no problem getting single subfolders, but I cannot find a way to have the "%/" functionality. Am I missing something?

Comment: AccountA { %:username/clear@imap.serverA.com:993!/ "Inbox" } AccountB { %:username/clear@imap.serverB.com:993!/ "Inbox" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.wl`, specify your primary account; this is the one that will be used for unqualified folder names, such as `%INBOX` or `%Trash`:

```
(setq elmo-imap4-default-server "imap.example.com"
      elmo-imap4-default-user "user"
      elmo-imap4-default-stream-type 'starttls)
```

In your `.folders`, specify the two hierarchies that you want to see in your Summary buffer:

```
%/
%:user@imap.serverB.example.org/
```

You may need to use double quotes around your user name if it contains any special characters, such as `@`.

Restart Wanderlust, go to the root of the folder hierarchy, and press `M-RET` twice.  You should see all of your folders appear.  The first time you enter a folder, you'll be prompted for a password.  Once you've entered all your passwords, say `M-x elmo-passwd-alist-save`.

You'll probably want to customise `wl-default-folder`, `wl-draft-folder`, `wl-trash-folder`.  Customising `wl-dispose-folder-alist` is useful if you want to avoid copying deleted messages between servers.  If one of the two servers is slow, you can prevent Wanderlust from checking it for new mail  using `wl-auto-uncheck-folders-alist`.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have an account such as "user@domain", I had to do user `"` around the `user`, such as: `%:"user@domain"@imap.serverB.example.org/`